# How do I assign PlotMarkers based on two different variables?

Tags: plotting, graphics, data, visualization

I'm trying to create ternary diagrams with 6 data points (samples) that each have two values - a type and a location. I have these two pieces:

```
duniteslist = {{0.14, 0.76, 0.1}, {0.04, 0.95, 0.01}};
websteriteslist = {{0.39, 0.08, 0.53}, {0.39, 0.08, 0.53}};
harzburgiteslist = {{0.09, 0.76, 0.15}, {0.11, 0.81, 0.08}};
sheeplist = {{0.14, 0.76, 0.1}, {0.39, 0.08, 0.53}, {0.09, 0.76, 0.15}};
bernardlist = {{0.04, 0.95, 0.01}, {0, 0, 1}, {0.11, 0.81, 0.08}};


plotbysite = 
 TernaryListPlot[{sheeplist, bernardlist}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Sheep", "Bernard"}]

plotbytype = 
 TernaryListPlot[{duniteslist, websteriteslist, harzburgiteslist}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Dunite", "Websterite", "Harzburgite"}, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

where I generate two separate diagrams - one that has different colors for type and one with different colors for site. This is fine, but I'm stuck on how to create one integrated plot, with differences in shape and color to indicate both site and type. For example, all the websterites could be red and all the Sheep Mountain samples could be triangles, etc. Is this possible, or is 2 separate plots the only way?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Could you add a short example of your lists so we have something to play with? In their absence, I'd probably go with applying a `Style` to each data point programmatically, and then passing the "annotated" data to the plotting function.

Comment: @MarcoB yes! Here are the lists: duniteslist = {{0.14, 0.76, 0.1}, {0.04, 0.95, 0.01}}, websteriteslist = {{0.39, 0.08, 0.53}, {0.39, 0.08, 0.53}}, harzburgiteslist = {{0.09, 0.76, 0.15}, {0.11, 0.81, 0.08}} and sheeplist = {{0.14, 0.76, 0.1}, {0.39, 0.08, 0.53}, {0.09, 0.76, 0.15}}, bernardlist = {{0.04, 0.95, 0.01}, {0, 0, 1}, {0.11, 0.81, 0.08}}. We took 3 samples (one of each type of rock) in each location (sheep and Bernard) and the coordinates are representing the relative percentages of minerals in each sample.

Answer (score 2):

Make each point its own dataset and style each dataset according to its type/location:

```
TernaryListPlot[{
  {{0, 0, 1}}, {{0.04`, 0.95`, 0.01`}},
  {{0.09`, 0.76`, 0.15`}}, {{0.11`, 0.81`, 0.08`}},
  {{0.14`, 0.76`, 0.1`}}, {{0.39`, 0.08`, 0.53`}}},
 PlotStyle -> {
   ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 1],
   ColorData[97, 2], ColorData[97, 1],
   ColorData[97, 2], ColorData[97, 2]},
 PlotMarkers -> {
   {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 15.`}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 13.`},
   {"\[FilledSquare]", 15.`}, {"\[FilledSquare]", 15.`},
   {"\[FilledCircle]", 13.`}, {"\[FilledDiamond]", 15.`}}]
```

[image]

I constructed the above code by constructing a `Dataset` from the OP's data in the following roundabout way. It's probably better to just enter the data into a `Dataset` or a CSV file and import it.

```
ds = Function[{comp},
     <|
      "Composition" -> comp,
      "Type" -> Replace[
        Select[{"duniteslist", "websteriteslist", "harzburgiteslist"},
          MemberQ[ToExpression@#, comp] &],
        {{name_} :> StringTrim[name, "list"],
         {} :> None}],
      "Location" -> Replace[
        Select[{"sheeplist", "bernardlist"}, 
         MemberQ[ToExpression@#, comp] &],
        {{name_} :> StringTrim[name, "list"],
         {} :> None}]
      |>
     ] /@ 
    Union[duniteslist, websteriteslist, harzburgiteslist, sheeplist, 
     bernardlist] // 
   ReplaceAll[
    s_String :> With[{name = StringTrim[s, "list"]}, name /; True]] //
   Dataset
```

[image]

This reproduces the plot above, with slightly larger filled-circle markers:

```
pm = AssociationThread[Union[Normal[ds[All, "Type"]]], 
   Take[Graphics`PlotMarkers[], 4] /. size_Real :> 15.];
colors = 
  AssociationThread[Union[Normal[ds[All, "Location"]]], 
   Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], 2]];

TernaryListPlot[
 Normal@ds[All, {#Composition} &],
 PlotStyle -> Normal@ds[All, colors[#Location] &],
 PlotMarkers -> Normal@ds[All, pm[#Type] &]
 ]
```